# How do I host my script in a Google Cloud server?

Tags: server, google-cloud-platform, host

So I have created something small which is a image-rehost where I wish to use Python script where I have a URL such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQpPA.jpg but with my rehost it would be

https://ip:port/abc123def456

so whenever I access that page it would give me the url that I posted here.

However the issue I am having is that I have no clue how to actually host the server that I made by node-js. Right now I just used the external IP with port of 5000. When I tried to send the image through my home ip by using the

```
https://external_ip:5000/abc123
```

the server doesn't recognize anything and nothing is being sent to the server which I in that case think I have setup something wrong.

I am using Google cloud server and I would wish to know how I can host my own server in the google cloud?

Answer (score 0):

As you are having trouble adding a firewall rule, I'm going to suggest make sure port 5000 is open and not 8888.
To open the firewall rule for port 5000 in Google Cloud Platform follow these steps.

1) Navigate to VPC Network > Firewall rules > Create firewall rule.

2) In the 'Create a firewall rule' page, select these settings:

Name - choose a name for this firewall rule

Network - select the name of the network your instance belongs to, most probably 
'default' unless you've configured a custom network.

Direction of traffic - 'Ingress'.

Action on match - 'Allow'.

Targets - 'All instances in the network'.

Source filter - 'IP ranges'.

Source IP ranges - '0.0.0.0/0'.

Second source filter - 'None'.

Specified protocols and ports - 'tcp:5000' or 'udp:5000' depending on whether the protocol you are using uses tcp or udp.

3) Hit 'Create'.

This will create a rule allowing traffic on port 5000 to all instances in your network from all IP address sources.

My advice would be to see if these settings work, and then once confirming this, lock down the settings by specifying a specific IP address or range of IP addresses in the 'Source IP ranges' text box, and adding a target tag to you instance and specifying 'Specified target tags' so the port is only open to the instance.

If this doesn't work, you may have a firewall rule turned on within the instance, which you would need to configure (or turn it off).

For more detailed information about setting firewall rules please see here.
For running Node.sj on GCE VM I will suggest you use the Bitnami Node.js package on GCP Marketplace which includes the latest version of Node.js, Apache, Python, and Redis. Using a pre-configured Node.js environment gets you up and running quickly because everything works out of the box. Manually configuring an environment can be a difficult and time-consuming hurdle to developing an application.

Also if you wish to do URL redirection you can use URL map feature provided with Google Cloud HTTP load balancer. This feature allows you to direct traffic to different instances based on the incoming URL. For example, you can send requests for http://www.example.com/audio to one backend service, which contains instances configured to deliver audio files, and requests for http://www.example.com/video to another backend service, which contains instances configured to deliver video files. You find steps to configure and more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/url-map).